# Do NSDouble, NSFloat, or other types than NSInteger exist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, types

Over at [In Cocoa do you prefer NSInteger or just regular int, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13725/4), there was mention of `NSDouble` and `NSFloat`, but I can't see a reference for those in any documentation. If `NSInteger`'s purpose is for architectural safety, what about other types such as `double` or `float`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP is talking about either. Those don't exist.

Comment: So double and float are architectural safe ? I can use double, but when it come to int I need to use NSInteger, just like that ?

Comment: I don't think *NSFloat*, *NSDouble* exist. But, I know CGFloat exist (Out of the context of the question. huh?)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`NSInteger` exists because the `int` type varies in size between 32-bit and 64-bit systems. `float` and `double` don't vary in size the same way, so there's no need to have wrapper types for them.

Comment: So what to do if I want to add a double to a NSArray? It accepts only objects.

Comment: Wrap it in a NSNumber object (which is a subclass of the more general NSValue).

Comment: Well, there is `CGFloat`, which is a `typedef` for `float` on 32bit and for `double` on 64bit. Which is pretty equivalent to what's been done with `NS(U)Integer`, I'd say.

Comment: Hmm. ... With 64bit iOS, we now need an NSFloat? - CGFloat is a fail (Apple libs outside of Quartz / CoreGraphics don't recognize CGFloat). I found Apple has an undocumented "CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE" define to workaround this (doh!) when you have to interface an Apple method that uses CGFloat to one that does not - and where a cast is impossible (e.g. because it takes a *float instead of a float).

Comment: @Adam hits on the issue I'm having, where we have a library that uses `CGFloat` (which is now double). Now as I replace `float`s with `double`s, I worry I'll be right back here one day when `CGFloat` eventually changes to something else.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `NSFloat` but I know the Core Graphics API eventually changed from `float` to `CGFloat` so that it could use a `double` on some architectures.

It is best to use the exact types that API headers declare.  This makes type changes automatic if you ever recompile your code for a different target.

Answer (score 0):

It's also about conventions.

A typedef to an int is incompatible to int int itself.

Example: pid_t is of type int, but passing an int would create a warning.

Why? Because you want to be sure that if you cross API boundaries everyone knows what the code expects.

There are float and double types, i.e NSTimeInterval. It's not really about the underlying type, but the convention to adhere to.

If you declare a local int as a loop counter and you do not plan to pass it to a well-defined API, it's fine to call an int an int.