# NSLog doesnt work with float?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am trying to do nslog on a float value using :

```
NSLog(@"THE LOG SCORE : %@", x);
```

and I have also tried :

```
NSLog(@"THE LOG SCORE : %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", x]);
```

but it doesnt work! any thoughts why it wouldnt work? the error I get is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

thanks

Comment: ios4 l0o0o0o0ol

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The %@ is intended to work on an object, a float is not an object.  To do a float try:

```
NSLog(@"THE LOG SCORE : %f", x);
```

Here's a helpful article

http://vormplus.be/blog/article/using-nslog-to-debug-your-iphone-application

Comment: You must be confusing NSFloat with CGFloat, which is just defined as 'float' and not an object.. Unless there's an NSFloat object i'm not aware of?

Comment: There is nothing like NSFloat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702923/does-nsdouble-nsfloat-nsother-than-nsinteger-exist

Comment: For information on other specifiers, see Apple's [String Format Specifiers Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: And NSInteger and NSUInteger aren't objects neither.

Comment: `CGFloat` is actually a `double` on 64 bit and a `float` on 32 bit architectures.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS always means that your are accessing an object that was already released.@x is dealing with objects.So be sure your variable "x" is an object that was alive.

Comment: In xcode4, Edit Scheme->Arguments->Environment variables,add NSZombieEnabled,set it to YES.U will locate the mistake.