# Why CGFloat has CG prefix not NS prefix?

Tags: ios, prefix, scalar, cgfloat

I have searched about CGFloat, and i found that it is just a typedef just like NSInteger and NSUInteger. But I want to know why it has CG prefix i.e. Core Graphics.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702923/do-nsdouble-nsfloat-or-other-types-than-nsinteger-exist

Answer (score 2):

As you know, the typedef `CGFloat` is defined in `CoreGraphics` framework, so it's prefix is `"CG"`.However, the typedef `NSInteger`is defined in `<objc/NSObjcRuntime.h>` and it's served as `Foundation` framework, which comes from `NextSTEP`, predecessor of `Cocoa`.

The `Naming Notation` of Apple SDK is taking `initial of it's framework` as prefix of all `Class`, such as `ABPersonViewController` defined in `AddressBook`framework.

Answer (score 1):

Because its part of **Core Graphics library**, not **Cocoa**. It stands for **Core Graphics**. The [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/index.html) framework is a C-based API that is based on the Quartz advanced drawing engine.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Obj-C` only has one namespace, in order to avoid namespace collisions, global objects and structs have prefixes attached to them. Apple reserves the right to use all two character prefixes, while three or more letter prefixes are open to public use. Because the `CGFloat` is implemented in the `Core Graphics` library, it uses the `CG prefix`. See Apple's documentation for `Obj-C` conventions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html